# How to cut up the value of the array in matlab based variable input

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, for-loop, plot

if I have an array of 1xN value where value is derived from the value of the array variable xy and z, how cut up the value of the array based on the value of such a point value x contains the value array number y and the result for the value of x.

```
xplot=[0];
for x=0:1:12;
   for y=0:0.5:5;
      for z=0:1:5;

         f=2.*x+3.*y+4.*z;

      end
   end
 end

xplot=[xplot;f]
```

I would like to divide the value of the array based on the value of z

```
xplotz0=[]
xplotz1=[]
 .
 .
 .
xplotzn=[]
```

because the end result I want to add all of these arrays

```
xzplottot = xplotz0 + xplotz1 + ... + xplotzn
```

or
if there is a temporary reservoir model of the array and collector array, so each value of z, the array will be fed to the collector array is then automatically entered into the collector array ... where the value of the array will be added continuously as the value of z the number of y.

Comment: try using `ndgrid` or `mesh` and avoid the loop.

Comment: in your current code, f is not an array, it is a scalar that is recalculated at every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
[x y z] = meshgrid( 0:1:12, 0:0.5:5, 0:1:5 )
f = 2.*x+3.*y+4.*z; %//all at once - no need for nested loop.
```

Now `f` is a 3D array, you can access `f` of different `z` values just by indexing the last dim

```
f(:,:,1)
```

gives you all `f` values for `z=0`

Comment: :) and xzplottot = sum(f,3)

Answer (score 0):

```
  XTable=[];
  for x=0:1:12;
  for y=0:0.5:5;
  z=0:1:5;    
  f=2.*x+3.*y+4.*z;
  XTable=[XTable f'];        
  end
  end
  XTableZ0=sum(XTable(1,:));
  XTableZ1=sum(XTable(2,:));
```

and so on.

=============